# Wordpress Contentberg theme latine extended - polish characters missing - issue

Tags: wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming, character, google-fonts

I have problem with wordpress page.

When in post, page is polish character - is not visible on web (like it was never be wrote). So instead of 'Śląsk' you will see: 'lsk'

Theme used on wordpress : Contenberg
Font setup on theme: Lato
Everywhere: turned on latine extend.

When you go to edit post you will see all this polsih characters - on live page there is not.

in database all data is correct and have proper characters.

font loaded when you run page:

`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%3A%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A400%7CLato%3A600%7CLato%3A700%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A400%7CLato%3A600%7CLato%3A700%7CLato%3A400%7CLato%3A600%7CLato%3A700%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A400%7CLato%3A600%7CLato%3A700%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A400%7CLato%3A600%7CLato%3A700%7CLato%3A400%7CLato%3A600%7CLato%3A700%7CLato%3A%7CLato%3A&subset=latin-ext`

[developer tool fonts loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCOO1.png)

Have no idea where can I find any other settings that can change displaying properly this characters.

I also check database encoding - UTF8, PHP - UTF8

Comment: Have you tried this on other computers or browsers?

Comment: Yes. Problem exist on all PC, browsers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem after few days fighting with.

The cause of the issue was plugin 'PB SEO friendly images'.

This plugin change encoding of whole wordpress, but do this in fly-mode so you will not see the changes in sources .

In settings there is information where you can change encoding:

[PB SEO encoding settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiPpt.png)

when you leave blank teoretically it should leave WP encoding deafult (which was utf8), but for some reason it changed. I just put there utf-8 and bang - polish characters back.

So issue resolved.